# Forcefully stopping the delayed job worker from Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

This is something common, but i am not finding a proper solution to it.  I want to stop the delayed job workers forcefully.  I am trying to use

```
script/delayed_job stop
```

but this is not doing anything, the process still continues in backgroud.  Mine is a Mac OSX development machine.

Comment: In which environment did you start your `delayed_job`? provide output for `ps aux | grep delayed_job` :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the workers forcefully (which seems like a bad idea) can't you just kill them like any other process?

```
kill -9 <parent-process-id>
```

I think (untested) you can find the process id with

```
ps aux | grep delayed_job
```